# Android. gif-ka не анимируется после вызова метода startAnimation();

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, adapter

Необходимо вывести список анимированных гифок. Для работы со списком использую адаптер. Класс приведён ниже:

class GifsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
    private final Activity context;
    ArrayList<GifInfo> gifInfoList;

    public GifsListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<GifInfo> gifInfoList) {
        super(context, R.layout.gifs_list, gifInfoList);

        this.context = context;
        this.gifInfoList = gifInfoList;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gifs_list, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gifNameTextView);
        txtTitle.setText(gifInfoList.get(position).getGifName());

        final GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.giphyImageView);
        new RetrieveByteArray(){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final byte[] bytes) {
                super.onPostExecute(bytes);
                gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
                gifImageView.startAnimation();
            }
        }.execute(gifInfoList.get(position).getGifUrl());



        return rowView;
    }

}
```

При формировании списка гифки появляются, но не анимируются. Может дело в модифкаторе final перед gifImageView ?
Класс RetreiveByteArray:

class RetrieveByteArray extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()== 200)
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int read;
                byte[] data = new byte[10240];
                while((read = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1){
                    buffer.write(data, 0, read);
                }
                buffer.flush();
                return buffer.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start animation это встроенный андроид метод у view, который запускает заданную анимацию перемещений, поворота и т.д. Возможно если у вашего компонента есть такой метод и он должен поиграть гифку, то startAnimation просто не переопределен. Посмотрите в реализацию этого метода в GifImageView. Если ни одна из причин выше не решившие проблемы, то ошибка уже где-то в GifImageView и там уже может быть все что угодно